# Mvc 3 login page redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to mvc 3 and i need help with the redirection after the autherntication coockie has times out. If a user logs in again after authentication times out the id love them to be redirected to the previous page

Answer (score 0):

If a user tries to go to a page that requires authorization the membership provider will automatically redirect back after login. By appending the querystring ReturnUrl. You can also manually do this. You just have to use %2f instead of /

/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fController%2fAction

Comment: Is the controller just a value or some kind of mvc  routing keyword the will do the redirection

Comment: I mean the controller in the url you posted

Comment: The controller is a generic name i used. It would be /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/Controller/Action

Comment: So lets say you have an action within a controller that requires a logged in user. The action is SendEmail in Controller Email. You would add [Authorize] above the action and a non-logged in user would be redirected to /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fEmail%2fSendEmail